# convert Rmd to ipynb with photo

Tags: windows, r-markdown, jupyter-notebook

I have [example.Rmd](https://gist.github.com/lcd1232/f069676445cdbb484baa) and I use command `notedown example.Rmd --knit > example.ipynb` but I have only file with this

```
{
 "cells": [],
 "metadata": {},
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 0
}
```

What the problem?

Comment: You might want to try filing an issue on [notedown](https://github.com/aaren/notedown). That seems like a bug.

Comment: Maybe knitr changed how to call them?